# How to vertically center text on the centerline of short lower-case letters in ConTeXt?

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, context-mkiv

I have a title in my document like this:

```
Birds of South America
```

“Birds”, “of”, and “South America” are each in different fonts and sizes, like this:

```
{\ssc Birds}
{\cga of}
{\ssd South America}
```

When I tried vertically centering the text, it centered them on the center of the whole height of the words. This does not look right though, because the lower-case letters are the strongest elements.

```
 _
| |
| | _  ← Vertically centered text centers text at the middle of the upper-case letters.
|_||_|
```

How can I vertically center each of these parts, where the center line is at the middle of the short lower-case letters?

```
 _
| |
| | _
|_||_| ← I need to place the vertical center line at the middle of the short lower-case letters in each word.
```

Comment: If you don't need a fully automatic solution you can tweak the vertical distance manually using raisebox: `\raisebox{2pt}\hbox{of}`

Comment: Please add a MWE. You can also use `\smash` to ignore the height of a particular box.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `location=middle` option of `\framed`.

```
\showboxes % For visual debugging

\defineframed[middleframed]
             [frame=off,
              location=middle]

\starttext

\startTEXpage[offset=3mm]
\dontleavehmode % Needed whenever you start a line with a \hbox
\middleframed{\ssc Birds}
\middleframed{\cga of}
\middleframed{\ssd South America}
\stopTEXpage

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

(Remove the `\showboxes` to get rid of the visual debugging information)